# How To Use Url Schemes With Search Engines In PyQt5

Tags: python, windows, pyqt, pyqt5

So, I want to be able to also search things up with a search engine but also being able to put in URLs in the url bar, so like a modern web browser like Google Chrome or Firefox.  This has to do with Schemes I'm pretty sure and the Scheme part of my script.  I tried to put a base url like "https://www.google.com/search?q=" or "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" but sadly that just errored out, then I tried to put the scheme as the regular https but then I put and else statement which stated that if there is no .com or .ca or www or https:// in the url bar when searched then it will search it up on the search engine, otherwise just put it as a url; that also errored out.  So, how could I approach this?  Also, any suggestions to how to make this more efficient?  Thank you in advance!  :D

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngine
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import os
import sys
 
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    #Constructor.
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.google.com"))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("Thing.png"))
        self.setStyleSheet("border: 0.2px solid black;")
        self.showMaximized()
 
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
 
        self.tabs.setDocumentMode(True)
 
        self.tabs.tabBarDoubleClicked.connect(self.tab_open_doubleclick)
 
        self.tabs.currentChanged.connect(self.current_tab_changed)
 
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
 
        self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.close_current_tab)
 
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
 
        self.status = QStatusBar()
 
        self.setStatusBar(self.status)
 
        navtb = QToolBar("Navigation")
 
        self.addToolBar(navtb)
 
        back_btn = QAction("Back.", self)
        #Setting status tip.
        back_btn.setStatusTip("Go Back To Previous Page.")
        #Adding action to back button.
        #Making current tab go back.
        back_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().back())
        #Adding this to the navigation tool bar.
        navtb.addAction(back_btn)
 
        next_btn = QAction("Forward.", self)
        next_btn.setStatusTip("Go Forward To Next Page.")
        next_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().forward())
        navtb.addAction(next_btn)
 
        #url_view = QAction("Url View", self)
        #url_view.setStatusTip(webEngineView.url().toString())
        #url_view.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().forward())
        #navtb.addAction(url_view)
 
        reload_btn = QAction("Refresh.", self)
        reload_btn.setStatusTip("Reload The Page.")
        reload_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().reload())
        navtb.addAction(reload_btn)
 
        home_btn = QAction("Home.", self)
        home_btn.setStatusTip("Go To The Home Page.")
 
        home_btn.triggered.connect(self.navigate_home)
        navtb.addAction(home_btn)
 
        navtb.addSeparator()
 
        self.urlbar = QLineEdit()
 
        self.urlbar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)
 
        navtb.addWidget(self.urlbar)
 
        stop_btn = QAction("Stop.", self)
        stop_btn.setStatusTip("Stop Loading The Current Page.")
        stop_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().stop())
        navtb.addAction(stop_btn)
 
        self.add_new_tab(QUrl("https://www.google.com"), "Homepage")
 
        self.show()
 
        self.setWindowTitle("")
 
    def add_new_tab(self, qurl = None, label ="Blank"):
 
        if qurl is None:
            qurl = QUrl("https://www.google.com")
 
        browser = QWebEngineView()
 
        browser.setUrl(qurl)
 
        i = self.tabs.addTab(browser, label)
        self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(i)
 
        #Update the url
        browser.urlChanged.connect(lambda qurl, browser = browser:
                                   self.update_urlbar(qurl, browser))
 
        browser.loadFinished.connect(lambda _, i = i, browser = browser:
                                     self.tabs.setTabText(i, browser.page().title()))
 
def tab_open_doubleclick(self, i):
        if i == -1:
            #Creating a new tab.
            self.add_new_tab()
 
    def current_tab_changed(self, i):
 
        qurl = self.tabs.currentWidget().url()
 
        self.update_urlbar(qurl, self.tabs.currentWidget())
 
        self.update_title(self.tabs.currentWidget())
 
    def close_current_tab(self, i):
 
        if self.tabs.count() < 2:
            return
        page = self.tabs.widget(i)
        self.tabs.removeTab(i)
        page.deleteLater()
 
        #self.tabs.removeTab(i)
 
    def update_title(self, browser):
 
        #If signal is not from the current tab.
        if browser != self.tabs.currentWidget():
            #Then do nothing.
            return
 
        title = self.tabs.currentWidget().page().title()
 
        page_icon = self.tabs.currentWidget().page().icon()
        self.setWindowTitle("")
        #self.setWindowTitle("")
 
    #Action to go to home.
    def navigate_home(self):
 
        self.tabs.currentWidget().setUrl(QUrl("https://www.google.com"))
 
    def navigate_to_url(self):
 
        #Convert it to QUrl object.
        q = QUrl(self.urlbar.text())
 
        if q.scheme() == "":
            qurl = (self.tabs.currentWidget()).url()
            q.setScheme("https")
 
        self.tabs.currentWidget().setUrl(q)
 
    def update_urlbar(self, q, browser = None):
 
        if browser != self.tabs.currentWidget():
 
            return
 
        self.urlbar.setText(q.toString())
 
        #Set cursor position.
        self.urlbar.setCursorPosition(0)
 
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 
app.setApplicationName("")
 
window = MainWindow()
 
app.exec_()
```

Comment: "that just errored out": what error? What have you actually tried?

Comment: I tried to put the full url "google.com/search?q=" then whatever you put it the url bar, but I don't think that's how schemes work.

Comment: I'm under the impression that you're complicating things for the wrong reason. If there is no scheme, then check its content (`q.path()`), check if it's a valid path for an url (and in that case set the scheme), alternatively just create a QUrl with the base search url and add the query: `if not q.scheme():` `q = QUrl('https://google.com/search?q=' + q.toString())`. Obviously, this is an extremely basic solution, proper url handling requires more knowledge of url paths. I'd recommend you to create a simple program with a basic line edit in order to check the result of your implementation.

Comment: Okay, so I put q as the value that you said, but now it always sets it to "https://www.google.com/?q=" then whatever was in the url bar, would I set the value of q back to the original value in the else statement if I wanted to only use the scheme (https)?  Please explain if you can.

Comment: It shouldn't, and if it does, then you did something wrong. Please read my comment more carefully.

Comment: Okay I read it more carefully and I came up with this.  `#If the scheme is blank.
        if q.scheme() == "":
            #Set a scheme.
            qurl = (self.tabs.currentWidget()).url()
            q = QUrl(self.urlbar.text())
            q.setScheme("https")
            q.path()
        #If not the scheme then.
        elif not q.scheme(self):
            q = QUrl("https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" + q.toString())
            q.path()`  Although, it stills doesn't work for some reason, I it's it's because of the change in the q variable.

Comment: It seems you're not understanding some basic concepts, especially about *truthfulness*. First of all, `q.scheme(self)` is just *wrong*. Then, since `QUrl.scheme()` returns a string, `if q.scheme() == ''` is ***exactly*** the same as `if not q.scheme()`. That condition I wrote in my post (which is the same as yours, but I thought that was implied) must be the first one, otherwise you'll be doing the same mistake as before. Please do more studying on string comparison and `if` statements: minding about URL schemes is pointless if you don't even know these basic and fundamental concepts.

Comment: I think I'm getting somewhere, now if I search something it will still will https:// then whatever you searched up, just if you press enter after that it searches it on duckduckgo!  I put q.path() at the top of the first if statement and I checked if q.scheme is not equal to "", so I think I am closer to the answer now!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QUrl.FromUserInput](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#fromUserInput):

```
def navigate_to_url(self):
        #Convert it to QUrl object.
        q = QUrl.FromUserInput(self.urlbar.text())
        if qurl.isValid():
            self.browser.load(qurl)
        else: 
            qurl = QUrl("https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%s" % q)
            self.browser.load(qurl)
```

But this doesn't work if the URL contain only one word.

Comment: Line 247 RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QWebEngineView has been deleted.

Comment: Please help if you can, I've been trying to solve this for so long!

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the new code?